# If $f(x)$ is diferentiable in $[0,1]$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$, then find $\alpha$ such that $f'(c)+\alpha f(c)=0$

Tags: calculus

Attempt:

Let $g(x)=e^{\alpha x}f(x)$

$g'(x)=\alpha e^{\alpha x}f(x)+e^{\alpha x}f'(x)$

$g'(c)=\alpha e^{\alpha c}f(c)+e^{\alpha c}f'(c)$

Now, $g(0)=f(0)$ and $g(1)=e^{\alpha }f(1)=e^{\alpha }g(0)$

Also, applying Rolle's theorem, there is at least one point $c$ such that $f'(c)=0$

How do I proceed further? at $\alpha=0$, $g'(c)=f'(c)+\alpha f(c)$. Hence this should be the approach.

Comment: are $c$ and $\alpha$ given or do you need to find $\alpha$ depending on $c$?

Comment: Is this an existential statement (of course $\alpha=-f'(c)/f(c)$), but that seems unlikely to be the intent of the question.  It seems that you're looking for cases where $g'(c)=0$.

Comment: Is $0\leq c\leq1$?

Comment: No. The question id for finding $\alpha$ and in the answer, its given that $\alpha$ is arbitary.

Comment: @Michael Burr, I have to find $\alpha$ values for which $f'(c)+\alpha f(c)=0$

Comment: Well, for $\alpha=0$ your conclusion is (trivially) correct.

Comment: Finding cases where $f'(c)+\alpha f(c)=0$ is equivalent to finding when $g'(c)=0$ by factoring out $e^{\alpha c}$, which is never zero.

Comment: Observe that if $f(x)=1$ is constant, then only $\alpha=0$ works.

Comment: I just called my friend. Its $f(1)=f(0)=0$

Comment: Excuse me, but what is $c$?

Comment: $c$ is a constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=e^{\alpha x}f(x)$.  Then 
$$g'(x)=\alpha e^{\alpha x}f(x)+e^{\alpha x}f'(x)=e^{\alpha x}(\alpha f(x)+f'(x)).$$
Since $e^{\alpha x}$ is never zero, $g'(x)=0$ iff $\alpha f(x)+f'(x)=0$.

Now, observe that $g(0)=f(0)=0$ and $g(1)=e^\alpha f(1)=0$.  Therefore, by Rolle's theorem, there is some $c$ in $(0,1)$ such that $g'(c)=0$.

Therefore, the result holds for *all* $\alpha$.

Comment: This is true only at ##c##?

Comment: It may or may not be only true at $c$, this shows the existence of a $c$ that satisfies the conditions (not that all $c$ work and not that any particular $c$ would work).